# Define styles for different line comments in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I would like to define new style for special comments like:

```
# this comment is in red
## this comment is in blue
```

or maybe even like this:

```
# -------------------------------------
# color such 3-line comment with green
# -------------------------------------
```

Is it possible somehow in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but you can make python `Docstring` a different color than a python `Line Comment`.

`Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->Python->Docstring->Click the box to the right of foreground->Choose red`

`Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->Python->Line Comment->Click the box to the right of foreground->Choose blue`

Then you will end up with...

```
"""
I 
am 
the color Red!
"""

# I 
# am 
# the color Blue!
```